# CakePHP - admin routing for /admin/, but not all the rest (way to set default admin false?)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I read the tutorial, and found that to use the "admin" prefix, you can just uncomment the:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

config/core.php file.

I did that, and my admin routing works great - /admin/users/add hits the admin_add() function in my users_controller.

The problem is - it's also changing my normal links - ie. my "LOGOUT" button now tries to go to /admin/users/logout instead of just /users/logout.  I realize I can add 'admin'=>false, but I'd rather not have to do that for every link in my site.

Is there a way to make it so ONLY urls with either 'admin'=>true or /admin/... to go to the admin, and NOT all the rest of the links?

Comment: It's because cake uses relative urls when generating the view. This helps when you're in a different plugin/custom route, but is a PITA when you want static routes. You'll need to either extend the helper or use static strings (which means you have to change them all anyway)

Comment: @JohnP Which of those would you recommend?  Extend the helper or use static strings?  I asked the question previously on StackOverflow, and it was agreed that it's better to use the arrays, so that's the way I went - but now it's sounding like static might be better/easier?

Comment: as usual, it depends. The advantage of arrays is that since you're sending named params cake will know exactly how to craft your url depending on routing. If you use static strings it's up to you. If you know the scope of the project, static strings are ok. Even easier would be to extend/wrap the url helper into your own helper. This will cover all your bases - 1) short string 2) easy to use 3) extensible.

Comment: @JohnP - It's a big project, and I don't yet know the complete scope, so I guess I'll stick with arrays... but that means I have to try to understand / learn what you said about extending the url helper :)  That seems like the answer to my question as well.  Would love to mark it as "answered" if you could put it into an answer format and maybe lead me in the right direction on how to extend the url helper, or an example, or link to where to learn about it...etc.  Thanks for your help so far, and thanks in advance if you help further!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on user Abba Bryant's edit, have a look at how to create a helper in the cook book : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1097/Creating-Helpers

If having to disable routing manually on all your links is an annoyance (it would be to me!), you could create a new helper `MyCustomUrlHelper` (name doesn't have to be that long of course), and have it use the core UrlHelper to generate the URLs for you.

```
class MyCustomUrlHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $helpers = array('Html'); 

    function url($controller, $action, $params ,$routing = false, $plugin = false) {
       //Example only, the params you send could be anything
       $opts = array(
          'controller' => $controller,
          'action'     => $action
          //....
       );

    }

   //another option

   function url($params) {
       //Example only, the params you send could be anything
       $opts = array(
          'controller' => $params['controller'],
          'action'     => $params['action']
          //....
       )
    }

   //just fill up $opts array with the parameters that core URL helper
   //expects. This allows you to specify your own app specific defaults

   return $this->Html->url($opts); //finally just use the normal url helper
}
```

Basically you can make it as verbose or terse as you want. It's just a wrapper class for the the actual URL helper which will do the work from inside. This allows you to give defaults that work for your specific application. This would also allow you to make a change in one place and have the routing for the whole application be updated.

## **EDIT**

You could also check whether the passed $opts array is a string. This way you can have the best of both worlds.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  It won't let me give the bounty yet (22 more hours), but this is the answer I was looking for - I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: So - When I create my links, I'll do something like this?: $this->Html->link('Click Here', $this->MyUrls->url('restaurants', 'view'));

Comment: Yeah, you could do that, or just add another link method in the helper to return the HTML version. So you can just call `$this->MyUrls->LINK('restaurants', 'view', $parms)`

Comment: Thanks for posting this - I hadn't logged in for a while and was hoping someone had answered this. Awesome job.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure if you use the prefix routing that you handle it in the HtmlHelper::link calls like so

```
<?php
    ...
    echo $html->link( array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'logout',
        'plugin' => false,
        'admin' => false,
    ));
    ...
?>
```

** EDIT **
You could extend the url function in your AppHelper to inspect the passed array and set the Routing.prefixes keys to false if they aren't already set in the url call.

You would then need to specify the prefix in your admin links every time.

Comment: Please read the full question prior to answering.  "I realize I can add 'admin'=>false, but I'd rather not have to do that for every link in my site."  (thanks for answer, but it doesn't answer my question)

Comment: Your edit sounds like what I might want to do - can you lead me in the right direction w/ that?  If I can get it to work, and you edit your original answer, I might be able to mark this one as "answered"!

Comment: I've added a 50 reputation bounty to this question - if you are able to better explain how I would extend the url function (maybe w/ an example?), I would love to mark this as answered and give you the rep that goes w/ it.

Answer (score 1):

The HtmlHelper accepts two ways of giving the URL: it can be a Cake-relative URL or an array of URL parameters.

If you use the URL parameters, by default if you don't specify the 'admin' => false parameter the HtmlHelper automatically prefixes the action by 'admin' if you are on an admin action.

IMHO, the easiest way to get rid off this parameter is to use the Cake-relative URL as a string.

```
<?php
//instead of using
//echo $this->Html->link(__('logout', true), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));

//use
echo $this->Html->link(__('logout', true), '/users/logout');
```

Kind regards,

nIcO

Comment: Doesn't the relative URL keep me from altering the routing later?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. '/users/logout' will always point to the action 'logout()' (and not admin_logout() or whatever_prefix_logout()) of the controller 'users'. (Off course, if you don't configure a specific route for this URL in routes.php)

Comment: Btw, when I started to use Cake, I used to write links with arrays of parameters, but I have soon realized that it was IMHO more stable (and less verbose) to use string parameters

Comment: I was told by multiple other people that it's better to use the arrays for the possibility of future routing purposes.  Anyway - the question is still there - using arrays, not url string - how do I keep use admin prefix thing without making it change all my links.

Comment: I have a few routes in my applications and they work with links that use strings. But I don't have any application with tons of routes, that's true. But another thing to mention is that the problem also exists if you are in a plugin. Links made of arrays prepend the url with plugins names as they do with current prefixes.

So the use of strings is maybe not perfect if you want to use routes intensively, but at least for me it is much more practical than arrays.

Comment: I appreciate the input.  Still looking for an answer to my question, but - never hurts to learn other things on the way.

Comment: If someone has a solution answering exactly your question, I would be happy to see it, because the problem you're facing was exactly the reason making me use strings in links. But I doubt there is one :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem this week and this code seemed to fix it. Let me know if it doesn't work for you and I can try to find out what else I did to get it to work.

```
$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
$this->Auth->loginAction = array(Configure::read('Routing.admin') => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
$this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(Configure::read('Routing.admin') => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout');     
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(Configure::read('Routing.admin') => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'welcome');
```

This was really frustrating, so I'm glad to help out.

Comment: well, I also added this to my users controller, which isn't the best, but probably did the trick. `    function admin_login(){
     $this->redirect(array('action'=>'login'));
    }`

Comment: The problem is, it's adding the prefix admin/ to EVERY link on the page, not just the logout button.  I mean.. even my navigation tries to go to /admin/restaurants for the restaurants page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I have a very good answer:

You can override the default behavior by creating an AppHelper class. Create app/app_helper.php and paste the following:

```
<?php
class AppHelper extends Helper{

    function url($url = null, $full = false) {
        if(is_array($url) && !isset($url['admin'])){
            $url['admin'] = false;
        }
        return parent::url($url, $full);
    }
}
?>
```

Unless it is specified when you call link() or url(), admin will be set to false.

Comment: I like this answer, but the question was for 1.3 - can you do this in CakePHP 1.3 as well?